# Is it possible to have popup options before adding a file using Dropzone.js?

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

I'm trying to implement the following workflow:

- User drags file(s) into dropzone area
- A bootstrap modal popup is show (with some settings for the user)
- After pressing 'okay' in that modal the files are added.

I tried catching the 'drop' and 'addedfile' but both of these do not give me the option to postpone the 'accept' event.

I know I can add this feature by editing dropzone.js but I wanted to ensure I did not miss some existing functionality before doing so.

Answer (score 1):

you can intercept the `addedfile` event, probably just like your thinking. but to remove the file from the dz queue, you need to call `removeFile`, when you intercept the event.

```
Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
    init: function () {
        this.on("complete", function (file) {
            console.log('Done!');
        });
        this.on("addedfile", function (file) {
            if(!confirm("Do you want to upload the file?")){
                this.removeFile(file);
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
};
```

You should be able to swap the call to the bootstrap confirm dialog with the js confirm dialog.